# fseek($file, SEEK_END) + fwrite() writing to beginning of file instead of end

Tags: php, json, io, fwrite

I'm trying to append a string to a file that contains a json string.
In order to do so, I must delete the last bracket "]", and append the new string at the end of the file.
This is how I tried to do it:

```
$fh = fopen($target_file, 'r+') or die("can't open file");  // opens file
$stat = fstat($fh);                                         // get data from statt struct
ftruncate($fh, $stat['size']-1);                            // remove last char
fseek($fh, SEEK_END);                                       // move file pointer to end
fwrite($fh, $append_str);                                   // write new string
fclose($fh);                                                // close
```

However, the $append_str gets written to the beginning of the file.
What should be different for the append operation to work?
(p.s.: using wamp server)

Comment: The solution proposed by Konstantin Rachev works.. but I'd still like to know why opening with "r+" and using fseek() would not work in this case..

Comment: This is an old question, but you haven't been answered (even though using `a+` is the right answer). The reason your code doesn't work is that you don't give the *offset* (e.g.: fseek($fh, **0**, SEEK_END)), in case anyone wonders. Use offset < 0 (e.g., -5, -27 etc)

Comment: @flen Can confirm, `fseek($fp, SEEK_END)` will fail, an offset _must_ be provided: `fseek($fp, 0, SEEK_END)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a+, it will set the file pointer at the end of your file.

Answer (score 2):

I see the second parameter is omitted, and that not how it works by `fseek`.

To set the file pointer to the end of file you need set offset parameter too:

```
fseek($fh, 0, SEEK_END);
```